# Jena Fuseki - Load ttl file into a graph (new or already present) in a dataset

Tags: rdf, jena, fuseki, triplestore, tdb

I'm using Apache Jena Fuseki 2.3.0.

I need to split my data into different graphs (two), so I have to specify the graph of a dataset to load the data into.

I need to use tdbloader but I can't figure out how the graph name can be specified on the command line.
I read the docs [here](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/) but I can't find any reference to the dataset graph name.

Any help is approciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Any reason for using an ancient version of Fuseki? The latest version is 3.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tdbloader has a `--graph=IRI` parameter.
Or you can load your data as n-quads, where the graph name is part of the data. 
tbdbloader, like most of the Jena utilities, accepts a --help parameter which will show you the options.

Comment: Yeah, I found it a little later, after I posted the answer and you anticipated me. I'm trying to make a sparql query on a dataset which contains a couple of graphs and the default graph (Fuseki made). Do you know whether exist a default standard graph uri? I need to use it in a from clause (and only in a from). I have to union the default graph and a specific graph so that the queries remain as they are.

Comment: The default graph URI is `<urn:x-arq:DefaultGraph\>`. There's some documentation on it [here](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/datasets.html).